# Multiple Websites - One Website Payments Pro Account?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway

Is it possible to have one Website Payment Pro account with Paypal but process payments from multiple websites? I have found the following link https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-faq-outside#Can_I_use_one_Payflow_Pro which states:

> **"Can I use one Website Payments Pro account for multiple websites?**
>
> Yes. You can use a single Website
>   Payments Pro account to process credit
>   card payments for multiple websites,
>   as long as all the payments are being
>   deposited into the same Internet
>   merchant account."

However, when I call the UK sales number, they state that *"multiple"* actually means only two websites and they have to be selling the same product.

Is there anyone who has any experience with this? Who is correct, the site or the sales hotline? Also, does anyone know any payment gateways that allow multiple website to flow through one account?

Many thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, PayPal cannot confirm this either way. Their website still says that you can accept payments from multiple accounts. I will have to go elsewhere.